# calling methods from different package JAVA

Tags: java, package

I have two packages; pack1 and pack2.
in pack1 I have two classes the main called Prog and another one called ClassA.
In pack2 I have one class called ClassB.

I am trying to understand why I can't call a method from ClassB using the object.
I can do that using the main class but not with another class.

Here's the code:

```
package pack1;
import pack2.ClassB;

public class Prog {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

Code for ClassA

```
package pack1;
import pack2.ClassB;

public class ClassA {
    ClassB o3 = new ClassB();
    // Error won't compile
    System.out.println(o3.getText());

}
```

Code for ClassB:

```
package pack2;

public class ClassB {
    final String TEXT = "This is a text";

    public String getText(){
        return TEXT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here isn't that you can't access the method. The problem is that statements must be enclosed either in a constructor, amethod-declaration or an initializer-block. So this would be valid code for example:

```
enter codepackage pack1;
import pack2.ClassB;

public class ClassA {
    ClassB o3 = new ClassB();

    public void someMethod(){
        System.out.println(o3.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why does it work like that ? in the main class I don't have to enclose it in a constructor.

Comment: @reddit_10 the mainclass contains a method-declaration, your version of `ClassA` contains a Statement (a StatementExpression to be more precise), which differs from a method-declaration. Take a look at the JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) - chapter 8.2 and 14.5 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

//pack1 code here

```
package pack1;

import pack2.ClassB;

class ClassA {

}

public class Prog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ClassB o3 = new ClassB();
        // Error won't compile
        System.out.println(o3.getText());


    }
}
```

//pack2 code here

```
package pack2;

public class ClassB {
    final String TEXT = "This is a text";

    public String getText() {
        return TEXT;
    }
}
```

You don't need to create class A you can directly import pack2 and its class, method